# How can I fingerprint a disk to check if it has been tampered with?

Tags: linux, luks

An example is cold storage of backups that include an operating system with LUKS disk encryption. How can I know the disk hasn’t been tampered with before entering the LUKS passphrase? I am looking for something similar to `openssl dgst -sha256 /path/to/file`, but for a whole disk (USB storage). How about the same at the partition level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitions are available as "files" too, so you can use the same tools :)

`openssl dgst -sha256 /dev/mapper/whatever-your-luks-storage-is`

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
dd if=/dev/disk_to_check|sha1sum
```

Of course you can change the hash algorithm to something else (sha256, sha3...)